# KnockoutJS: Does passing one observble array as a parameter to another bind them?

Tags: knockout.js

I have two observable arrays in my app, and i passed one as a parameter to the other,

```
model.arrayone(model.arrayTwo);
```

i noticed that what ever i push in arrayOne automatically enters arrayTwo, does that mean they are binded together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The behavior you're describing

What you're doing is a bit weird. Here's a reproduction:

```js
const arr1 = ko.observableArray([1]);
const arr2 = ko.observableArray([2]);

arr2(arr1);
arr2.push(2);

console.log(arr1()); // [ 1, 2 ]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

### Why it works

This behaviour works because of the `ko.observableArray` implementation of `push`. The way this method works, is that it *peeks* at the observable array's inner value and calls the `push` method on that object. From the source:

> ```
> ko.utils.arrayForEach(["pop", "push", "reverse", "shift", "sort", "splice", "unshift"], 
>   function (methodName) {
>     ko.observableArray['fn'][methodName] = function () {
>         // Use "peek" to avoid creating a subscription in any computed that we're executing in the context of
>         // (for consistency with mutating regular observables)
>         var underlyingArray = this.peek();
>         this.valueWillMutate();
>         this.cacheDiffForKnownOperation(underlyingArray, methodName, arguments);
>         var methodCallResult = underlyingArray[methodName].apply(underlyingArray, arguments);
>         //                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>         this.valueHasMutated();
>         // The native sort and reverse methods return a reference to the array, but it makes more sense to return the observable array
>         // instead.
>         return methodCallResult === underlyingArray ? this : methodCallResult;
>     };
> });
> ```

<sub>[source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/observableArray.js#L120)</sub>

Now, as you can imagine, this will cause a *chain* of `push` methods being forwarded until there's no longer an observable array. I.e.:

1. Call to `arr2.push`
2. `observableArray arr2` does `.peek()` and finds a reference to `observbaleArray arr1`
3. Call to `arr1.push`
4. `observableArray arr1` does `.peek()` and finds a reference to the *regular* array `[1]`
5. `Array.prototype.push` on `[ 1 ]` adds `2` to end up as `[ 1, 2 ]`

Then:

6. Evaluate `arr1` returns `[ 1, 2 ]`

### Why it's wrong to nest `observableArray`s like this:

When constructing an observable array with anything other than `null`, `undefined` or an array instance, you're greeted by this handy error message:

```js
try {
  ko.observableArray(ko.observableArray([]));
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

When *setting* an observable array, this check is no longer performed (probably because of performance?). The rule still applies though:

- Use `observableArray`s *only* for holding arrays
- Use regular `observable`s for anything else

Answer (score 1):

if `model.arrayTwo` is ko.observableArray and `model.arrayone` is ko.observableArray then doing `model.arrayone(model.arrayTwo);` will assign `model.arrayTwo` as a reference to your observable `model.arrayone`. That doesn't mean thay are binded, that's mean they reference to the same place in memory..

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that both observable arrays become tied to the same underlying array. An observable array is basically a wrapper around the standard javascript array so when you initialize one observable using another they become reflections of the same data.

They aren't "bound" in the knockout data-binding sense, but they are bound in that they each have references to the same source data.